# Laravel 5 Bind data to var for menu in header.blade.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

What is the best solution for creating a menu.
I have $menudata (dynamic from dbase) and want to pass it to a heade.blade.php to generate top menu.

```
$menudata = Menu::all();

@foreach($menudata as $value).......
```

How can i achieve that? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: I think you are using  [Laravel Menu](https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu)as laravel package for menu. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code within the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider`

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('menudata', Menu::all());
});
```

Here, * means all views will receive `$menudata`.

Now you can use this like

```
@foreach ($menudata as $menu).....
```

Comment: I choose for this one because i can choose a view like this, View::composer('partitials.header', function($view)
     {
      $view->with('menudata', ['aaa','bbb']);
     }); Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

If the menu is visible in every page then add the following in any service provider (e.g. in the `AppServiceProvider`):

```
 public function boot() {
    // ...
    View::share("menudata",Menu::all());
   //...
}
```

Then you can use the menu data in any view e.g.

```
 @foreach($menudata as $value).......
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-menu provides three rendering methods out of the box. However you can create your own rendering method using the right methods and attributes.

As noted earlier, laravel-menu provides three rendering formats out of the box, asUl(), asOl() and asDiv(). You can read about the details [here](https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu#rendering-methods).

```
{!! $MyNavBar->asUl() !!}
```

You can also access the menu object via the menu collection:

```
{!! Menu::get('MyNavBar')->asUl() !!}
```